# Was the ending of Scarlet and Violet changed for Chinese audiences?

Tags: version-differences, pokemon-scarlet-violet

[Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Scarlet_and_Violet) indicates there are three Chinese versions:

- Cantonese
- Mandarin (Mainland China)
- Mandarin (Taiwan)

In any of these versions, was the plot altered so that instead of

> Paradox Pokémon coming from the past (Scarlet) or future (Violet)

they came from

> "imagination"?

A Twitter post [discussed on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokeLeaks/comments/ytglli/story_plot_leak_major_spoilers_and_truth_of/) says that this is the case. However, that was posted before the games were officially released. Even if it is true, I'm looking for more details on which parts were changed.